# Why the "stop" input doesnt stop the hitorstop() and run the code for the condition elif todo == "stop"

Tags: python-3.x, function, oop

```
import random
class Player:
    deck = ["A♣", "2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "K♣", "Q♣", "A♦", "2♦", "3♦", "4♦", "5♦",
            "6♦", "7♦", "8♦", "9♦", "10♦", "J♦", "K♦", "Q♦", "A♥", "2♥", "3♥", "4♥", "5♥", "6♥", "7♥", "8♥", "9♥",
            "10♥", "J♥", "K♥", "Q♥", "A♠", "2♠", "3♠", "4♠", "5♠", "6♠", "7♠", "8♠", "9♠", "10♠", "J♠", "K♠", "Q♠"]

    total = 0
    run = True
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Enter your name : ")
        self.Bet = inputs.bet(self)
        self.Aceval = inputs.Aval(self)

class Dealer:
    deck = ["A♣", "2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "K♣", "Q♣", "A♦", "2♦", "3♦", "4♦", "5♦",
            "6♦", "7♦", "8♦", "9♦", "10♦", "J♦", "K♦", "Q♦", "A♥", "2♥", "3♥", "4♥", "5♥", "6♥", "7♥", "8♥", "9♥",
            "10♥", "J♥", "K♥", "Q♥", "A♠", "2♠", "3♠", "4♠", "5♠", "6♠", "7♠", "8♠", "9♠", "10♠", "J♠", "K♠", "Q♠"]

    total = 0
class inputs:
    def bet(self):
        """
        takes in the bet from the user and stores it in the player class
        :return: output
        """
        self.bet = input("Enter the amount for your bet : ")
        output = self.bet
        if self.bet.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Use your monke brains and enter correct input")
            return inputs.bet(self)
        else:
            return int(output)

    def Aval(self):
        """
        Takes the value for ace and stores it in the player class
        :return: output
        """
        self.aval = input("Enter the value for ACE (1 or 10) : ")
        output = self.aval
        if self.aval.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Use your monke brains and enter correct input")
            return inputs.Aval(self)
        elif self.aval.isnumeric() == True:
            if self.aval in ["1", "10"]:
                return int(output)
            else:
                print("I understand you suffer braincell deficiency but I need you to fire up those 2 braincells you have and enter the proper number")
                return inputs.Aval(self)

    def valcalc(card):
        """
        takes the card for player.deck and returns the value of that card
        :return: card value
        """
        if card[0] in ("K", "Q", "J"):
            return 10
        elif card[0] == "A":
            return p.Aceval
        else:
            if len(card) > 2:
                return int(card[0:2])
            else:
                return int(card[0])

def hitorstop(todo):
    if todo.lower() == ("hit" or "stop"):
        if todo.lower() == "hit":
            pcard = random.choice(Player.deck)
            dcard = random.choice(Dealer.deck)
            print("\nYour card is : ", pcard)
            Player.deck.remove(pcard)
            Dealer.deck.remove(dcard)
            p.total += inputs.valcalc(pcard)
            d.total += inputs.valcalc(dcard)
            print("Your total is : ", p.total)
            if p.total > 21:
                print("You lost lol")
                return
            elif d.total > 21:
                print("You won , sheeesh")
                return
            elif (p.total == d.total) == 21:
                print("Its a tie")
                return
            else:
                hitorstop(input("\n\nDo you want to hit or stop : "))
        else:
            if todo.lower() == "stop":
                pnum = 21 - p.total
                dnum = 21 - d.total
                if dnum > pnum:
                    print(p.name, "wins")
                    return
                elif pnum > dnum:
                    print("You lost against a dealer bot  , such a shame")
                    return
                else:
                    print("Its a tie , you didnt win shit , lol")
                    return
            else:
                hitorstop(input("\n\nDo you want to hit or stop : "))
    else:
        hitorstop(input("\n\nDo you want to hit or stop : "))

p = Player()
d = Dealer()

pcard = random.choice(Player.deck)
dcard = random.choice(Dealer.deck)
print("\nYour card is : ", pcard)
print("Dealer's card is :" + str(dcard) + "+")
Player.deck.remove(pcard)
Dealer.deck.remove(dcard)
p.total += inputs.valcalc(pcard)
d.total += inputs.valcalc(dcard)
print("Your total is : ", p.total)

hitorstop(input("Do you want to hit or stop : "))
```

Why does the code below todo == "stop" run when i put in stop as input , it just keeps looping asking for the input again and again if i put "stop" for hitorstop() function
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the line `todo.lower() == ("hit" or "stop"):` with `todo.lower() in ("hit", "stop"):` to make it work.
However, this entire condition is redundant in the first place and you can remove it.
You don't need it since you compare the input with "hit" and "stop" later, so it is useless to compare twice.

Here is the replace:

```py
def hitorstop(todo):
    if todo.lower() == "hit":
        pcard = random.choice(Player.deck)
        dcard = random.choice(Dealer.deck)
        print("\nYour card is : ", pcard)
        Player.deck.remove(pcard)
        Dealer.deck.remove(dcard)
        p.total += inputs.valcalc(pcard)
        d.total += inputs.valcalc(dcard)
        print("Your total is : ", p.total)
        if p.total > 21:
            print("You lost lol")
            return
        elif d.total > 21:
            print("You won , sheeesh")
            return
        elif (p.total == d.total) == 21:
            print("Its a tie")
            return
        else:
            hitorstop(input("\n\nDo you want to hit or stop : "))
    elif todo.lower() == "stop":
        pnum = 21 - p.total
        dnum = 21 - d.total
        if dnum > pnum:
            print(p.name, "wins")
            return
        elif pnum > dnum:
            print("You lost against a dealer bot  , such a shame")
            return
        else:
            print("Its a tie , you didnt win shit , lol")
    else:
        hitorstop(input("\n\nDo you want to hit or stop : "))
```